# why don't save data from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, server

hey i want to crawl data from the site with this code (js)

```
var i = 0
var oldValue = -1

var interval = setInterval(get, 3000);

function get(){
var x= $($('.table-body')[1]).find('.h-col-1')
if(i!=5){
if(oldValue != x){
    oldValue = $(x[1]).text()
    console.log($(x[1]).text())
    ++i
    sendPost($(x[1]).text())
  }
}else clearInterval(interval)
}

function sendPost(par) {
    var te= $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://localhost/sa.php',
        data: {json:JSON.stringify({
            num : par
        })  },
    }).done(function( data ) {
        console.log("done");
    })
    .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);textStatus
    });
    console.log(te)
```

send data from localhost and save on my sql and this php code

sa.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$sitename = "http://localhost/";
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "db";
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
$insert = "INSERT INTO main(number, time, date) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','')";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$result = mysqli_query($connect,sprintf($insert,$data['num'] ,date("H:i:s"),date("Y-m-d")));


?>
```

and then

[image: pic success]

success send from js request from local  server why dosen't save on the my sql ??

Comment: do you have any errors  ?

Comment: maybe this cause an issue, `date("Y-md")` what is your datatype of `date` column? i suppose to be typo here.. isnt it? TRY WITH `date("Y-m-d")`

Comment: devpro yes is column datatype is datetime

Comment: you send `json:{"num": "4.58"}` - can't see where you access the `json` parameter in PHP

Comment: DATETIME will be accept `Y-m-d` not `Y-md`

Comment: Why are you using sprintf instead of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) ???

Comment: @Mohammed Yassine CHABLI not give an error

Comment: @devpro i change this! but not work

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer lies into your insert query:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO main(number, time, date) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','')";
```

Please count the number of columns defined and the number of values you're trying to insert. These two should, obviously, match.

If you wish to figure out why a MySQL query failed, just print or log the error:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 2):

You should check the value of `file_get_contents("php://input")`.

As you are sending a key-value pair:

```
    data: {json:JSON.stringify({
        num : par
    })  },
```

you should get the data using `$_POST['json']`.

So:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
```

The alternative, change the javascript instead of the php, would be something like:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        num : par
    }),
```

But to be honest, I don't know how jQuery will handle that data so it might need some tweaking.

Apart from that, you have an sql injection problem; you should use prepared statements with bound parameters instead.

Comment: Undefined variable: POST in C:\xampp\htdocs\sa.php on line 11

Comment: @hamid That was a typo on my side, the correct variable is `$_POST`.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: json in C:\xampp\htdocs\sa.php on line 13

Comment: the last night it's  right but now...